# How to set up mail server(postfix or anything else) on ubuntu?

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta, mail-server

I have installed Ubuntu Bionic on my virtual machine and have an application set up.

Now what I need is to send emails from my own server.

I am trying to set up postfix to do that but nothing works. I have tried many tutorials but still no success....even worse - the more tutorials I try the more confused I get.

So what have I tried?

1. I used `apt install mailutils` to install postfix and I chose `internet site` 
   When it asked for FQDM I entered `mydomain.com` . 
   Here  is the first question. Some tutorials say to change it to `mailmydomain.com` . 
   So is it supposed to be a subdomain?
   Do I need to create an A record to my DNS?
2. The I try to send an email

```
email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" somemail@mail.com
```

But nothing happens...no mail in my mailbox and no mails in posfix queue.

1. Is there a step by step tutorial for a complete beginner?
2. Do I need to create a MX record pointing to my server?
3. Do I need to create a TXT record? I read that that is how other mail servers validate a sender. 
   If yes, then how to do it?
4. So what do I have to do to send and email from my own server?
   At this point I don`t even need to receive and email - just send it

And I don`t need to use postfix...I can use whatever works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire So in that case all your future python related questions has to be closed because they belong to https://www.python.org/

Comment: That's a fallacy. askubuntu.com is a Stack Exchange website. It's a sister site of Stack Overflow, dedicated to Ubuntu. That's why I voted to close with that motive. Furthermore, you ask for resources (which is forbidden on Stack Overflow) and Ubuntu-specific people on askubuntu.com are better positioned to help you further. In short, you'll get better answers there than here.